# Face issue to get data from sales_order_tax_item table

Tags: magento2, tax

I am facing issue to get data from `sales_order_tax_item` table from `checkout_submit_all_after` event when place order using guest customer but for register customer, it works well.

When I try to get data from `sales_order_tax_item` table for the guest customer order at that time entry is not there in that table but for the register, user same code works well.

```
    $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
    $resource = $objectManager->create('Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection');
    $write = $resource->getConnection('default');
    $order = $observer->getEvent()->getData('order');        
    $table = $resource->getTableName('sales_order_tax_item');
    $items = $order->getAllItems();
    foreach ($items as $key => $item) {
        $itemId = $item->getId();
        $taxItems = $write->query("SELECT * FROM " . $table . " WHERE item_id='" . $itemId . "'")->fetchAll();

    }
```

I have also add log in `Magento\Tax\Model\Plugin\OrderSave.php` after this statement. But I am getting an empty result for guest customer.

```
 $taxItem = $this->taxItemFactory->create();
 $taxItem->setData($data)->save();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you used wrong observer event. For that, try to use `checkout_onepage_controller_success_action` observer event.

**events.xml :**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="checkout_onepage_controller_success_action">
        <observer name="directpost_update_all_edit_increments" instance="RH\Helloworld\Observer\UpdateObserver" />
    </event>
</config>
```

**UpdateObserver.php :**

```
<?php

namespace RH\Helloworld\Observer;

class UpdateObserver implements \Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface {
    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer) {
        $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
        $resource = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection');
        $connection = $resource->getConnection();
        $tableName = $resource->getTableName('sales_order_tax_item');
        $order = $observer->getEvent()->getData('order');
        $items = $order->getAllItems();
        $writer = new \Zend\Log\Writer\Stream(BP . '/var/log/Rohan.log');
        $logger = new \Zend\Log\Logger();
        $logger->addWriter($writer);
        foreach ($items as $key => $item) {
            $itemId = $item->getId();
            $sql = "SELECT * FROM " . $tableName . " WHERE item_id='" . $itemId . "'";
            $taxItems = $connection->fetchAll($sql);
            $logger->info(print_r($taxItems, true)); // You can see an array of tax items in log
        }
        return $this;
    }
}
```

**Hope, It maybe helpful for you.**

Comment: Thanks, it works